# ShareKit - How can I know if one user already authorized my app on Twitter?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, sharekit

I have a app that send messages for Twitter. I'm writing a "view settings" and I'd like to know if the user already autorized my app on Twitter. I have the fields "username" and "password", how can I check if the user already authorized?

I'm using ShareKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SHKTwitter *checkTwitterLoging = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init];

if (![checkTwitterLoging isAuthorized]) {
        NSLog(@"Not login");

}else{

       NSLog(@"User login");

}
[checkTwitterLoging release];
```